# Suggested edits on orphaned tag wiki excerpts go missing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I submitted a suggested edit on a tag wiki (both wiki and excerpt, both approved). That tag apparently ended up being deleted for some reason or another. This is how it shows up in my activity tab:

[image]

- [Tag wiki edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1467) — still shows up as edit to "orphan wiki"
- [Excerpt edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1468) — **500 Internal Server Error**

The weird thing is, looking up the [excerpt's post history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/28938/revisions) (ID of the tag wiki + 1) still works fine.

Comment: This no longer seems to happen, so, hooray I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gotta assume this was fixed at some point, but like you said, it doesn't happen now.

Comment: Reproduced. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3488231/ace?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1 (Three suggestions on 3 Jul) (No-repro on the 500 Error part, but reproduced the blank entry in activity tab.)

Comment: Those load fine for me, @ace - what do you see?

Comment: Sorry I meant the blank entry in activity tab, not the 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Oh, yeah - that was never fixed.

Comment: So should I file a separate bug report? Or is this decided to be wont-fix?

Comment: Write it up if you like; I'm not sure we store the information to fix this properly, but perhaps there is a solution that could reduce confusion.